# data not getting inserted properly

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Here am having two tables named services and payment and am having two forms for inserting values in to it..when i enter data in to services there am getting two rows names id and customer_id and i want to generate those values in to payment table while adding to the corresponding id..
This is my services table..

```
    id  code     customer_id    particulars     serialno    complaint   
    22  ORD00022    16             tv             100         ddfds     
    23  ORD00023    19             GH             565          gfdg     
    24  ORD00024    15             tv             122         sdfsd     
    25  ORD00025    16             cvbcv           5         tgtdfgfg   
    26  ORD00026    16             cvbcv           5         tgtdfgfg
```

This is my payment table

```
id      order_id    customer_id   actual_amount   paid_amount   balance     type
3          0            0              250.00       100.00       150.00     Cash
4          0            0              250.00       50.00        100.00     Cash
5          0            0              150.00       50.00        100.00     Credit
10         0            0              500.00       500.00       400.00     Credit
13         26           16             250.00       100.00       0.00       Cash
```

This my view page

```
<li> <a href="" class="make_payment" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".payment" id="<?php echo $row->id; ?>" customer-id="<?php echo $row->customer_id; ?>" >Make Payment</a> </li>
 <div class="modal payment">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>account_control/make_payment" method="post" id="assign-form">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Make Payment</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     <div class="box-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Total Amount</label>

        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="total_amount" id="total_amount" placeholder="Total Amount">
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div> 
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Paid Amount</label>

        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="paid_amount" id="paid_amount" placeholder="Paid Amount">
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div> 
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Balance</label>

        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="balance" id="balance" placeholder="Balance">
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div> 
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Balance</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <select name="type" class="form-control">
            <option value="Cash">Cash</option>
            <option value="Credit">Credit</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div> 
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="order_id" id="order_id">
      <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" id="customer_id">        
    </div>


    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Pay">
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</form>
```

My controller looks like this..

```
public function make_payment()
{
    $status = $this->Account_model->make_payment();
    if($status)
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Payment successful');
    }
    else
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Payment Failed');
    }
    redirect('account_control/view_order');
}
```

My model looks like this

```
public function make_payment()
{  

    $paid = $this->input->post('paid_amount');
    $total = $this->input->post('total_amount');
    $balance = $this->input->post('balance');
    $customer_id = $this->input->post('customer_id');
    $order_id = $this->input->post('order_id');

    $data = array('order_id' => $order_id,
        'customer_id' => $customer_id,
        'actual_amount'=>$total,
        'paid_amount' => $paid,
        'balance' => $balance
    );

    if($this->db->insert('payment',$data))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

if both included in one form iam getting it correctly now its showing error like this

```
Error Number: 1048

Column 'order_id' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `payment` (`order_id`, `customer_id`, `actual_amount`, `paid_amount`, `balance`) VALUES (NULL, 'NULL', '100', '50', '50')

Filename: C:/wamp64/www/account/application/models/Account_model.php

Line Number: 196
```

This is my output view from the makep payment below action displays the modal

```
  S.No    Order #          Date   Particulars   Serial/IME No  Complaints    Action
   1       ORD00027   06/07/2016    led            11          sedsdf       make payment

   2       ORD00026   06/13/2016    cvbcv           5          tgtdfgfg     make payment
```

the last row i inserted in the payment table is the value i assumed that i should have to get

Comment: This error is self-explanatory and has little to do with your app code.  The `order_id` column is set to be not nullable in your database.  Either `ALTER COLUMN` or do a null check before inserting.

Comment: you have not set the value of hidden field order_id, customer_id that's why it is blank and that not allowed to insert any new record

Comment: i had given hidden field for order_id and customer_id

Comment: It tables show incorrect values... how can order id and customer id be zero... and even if we assume they can be zero... how do different customers have same id or different orders have same order id? This is incorrect... please do verify

Comment: Here order_id value is the value of id in services table and customer_id can be same because same customer can take order at different times

Answer (score 0):

in Model

```
$paid = $this->input->post('paid_amount');
$total = $this->input->post('total_amount');
$balance = $this->input->post('balance');
$order_id_data = $this->input->post('order_id');
$customer_id_data = $this->input->post('customer_id ');
  if(order_id_data ==""){

       $order_id="";

 }



  if(customer_id_data ==""){

       $customer_id ="";

 }
$data = array('order_id' => $order_id,
    'customer_id' => $customer_id,
    'actual_amount'=>$total,
    'paid_amount' => $paid,
    'balance' => $balance
);

if($this->db->insert('payment',$data))
{
    return TRUE;
}
else
{
    return FALSE;
}
```

try this

Comment: see that is not my problem this problem can be easily solves by changing the null at the database..my problem is corresponding id and customer_id should entered in to the payment table like my last row in the payment

Answer (score 0):

have you checked to make sure that the $data array actually contains the value for order_id?
Either do

```
    $data = array('order_id' => $order_id,
        'customer_id' => $customer_id,
        'actual_amount'=>$total,
        'paid_amount' => $paid,
        'balance' => $balance
    );
print_r($data);
```

or

```
    $data = array('order_id' => $order_id,
        'customer_id' => $customer_id,
        'actual_amount'=>$total,
        'paid_amount' => $paid,
        'balance' => $balance
    );
log_message('error', print_r($data, TRUE));
```

Comment: Yes i had checked the array doesn't  contain the value of order_id and customer_id